# how to make loop for data table in R?

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a task to do as following for numerous rows and I would like to know if it's possible to use the loop for such computations without typing the rows one by one.

I've tried but it seems like within the [] brackets, the function doesn't seem to have overrule what I would like to do. Any suggestions appreciated!

```
data[, d1:= difference < 2]
data[, d2:= difference < 3]
data[, d3:= difference < 4]
data[, d4:= difference < 5]
data[, d5:= difference < 6]
data[, d6:= difference < 7]
data[, d7:= difference < 8]
data[, d8:= difference < 9]
data[, d9:= difference < 10]
data[, d10:= difference < 11]

data$d1 <- as.numeric(data$d1)
data$d2 <- as.numeric(data$d2)
data$d3 <- as.numeric(data$d3)
data$d4 <- as.numeric(data$d4)
data$d5 <- as.numeric(data$d5)
data$d6 <- as.numeric(data$d6)
data$d7 <- as.numeric(data$d7)
data$d8 <- as.numeric(data$d8)
data$d9 <- as.numeric(data$d9)
data$d10 <- as.numeric(data$d10)
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `lapply`. Provide a reproducible example and we could show you. Why do you use (slow) data.frame assignment for `as.numeric`?

Comment: Because I would like to calculate the difference but just don't know how to count logi type with data table, so I thought I'd do that instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a `for` loop and assign (`:=`) to create new columns

```
for(j in 1:10){
    data[, paste0("d", j) := as.integer(difference < (j+1))]
}
```

Or using `set`

```
data[, paste0("d", 1:10) := 0L]
for(j in 1:10){       
   set(data, i = which(data[["difference"]] <  (j + 1)), j = paste0("d", j),
        value = 1L)
}
```

Comment: Usually preferable to use `set` with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add an alternative to the already working and accepted answer, it is possible to call `lapply` within a single `data.table` call, such that several columns are created at once. In your case:

```
j <- seq_len( 10 )
data[ , paste0("d", j) := lapply( j+1, function(x) ( difference < x ) * 1L ) ]
```

Note the column names (before the `:=`) are represented as a vector, and the column contents are represented as elements of a list (the output of `lapply`).